# Rename the ironrouter tag to iron-router

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I realize this is a very minor issue, but it's bugging me -- tags on SO that contain two or more words are separated with dashes (that I've seen). Can somebody rename [ironrouter](/questions/tagged/ironrouter) to `iron-router`? That is the name of the actual iron-router package it's a tag for.

EDIT: I emailed the developer, who replied:

> It should be iron-router (I think that's easier to see). I should just update the README with Iron Router instead of IronRouter.

Comment: "ironrouter" is surprisingly hard to get good search results for. You're not talking about [this project](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), are you? Because according to the README file, "IronRouter" is one word. And since our tags are not case-sensitive, that would appear as [tag:ironrouter].

Comment: I am talking about that project! The README does specify "IronRouter" as the project name, but it also shows that "iron-router" is the package name, and also the name you'd use to add the package to your project, etc. Therefor, it seems to me it makes more sense to use the package name.

Comment: You can check it out in the official package repo: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/iron-router

Comment: So if an abbreviation were used for the package name (e.g. "ir"), should we use that as the name of the tag? I don't think so. I think the official project name is a better choice. That's the name that the developer picked free of any external considerations (e.g. length, no Unicode support, etc.).

Comment: You definitely have a point, I'm not arguing you're wrong. But this is how most people in the community would ask about it. If you look over most posts in the places the community goes to ask for help (e.g. google groups, SO, IRC, etc.) you'll mostly find that people ask about iron-router package, rather than IronRouter.

Comment: Actually, I'll go ask the developer.

Comment: @CodyGray I've just heard back from the developer, who voted for `iron-router`

Comment: +1 for emailing the developer. :-)